# Android Retrofit post request doesn't reach server

Tags: android, json, post, response, retrofit

I have very strange issue. Post request doesn't reach server. I have **HttpInterceptorLogger**

, so i see logs(see below). Other post requests work correctly, but they didn't send json:

Also checked this request via browser and it worked fine. No idea where could be an issue. Please help to fix it.

I have request:

```
@POST(LEAD_SET)
Observable<ResponsePojo<LeadsPostPackage>> setFullLead(@Body RequestPojo<LeadsPostPackage> leadsRequestPojoRequestPojo)
```

And this is response:

```
05-31 11:50:06.682 20489-20489/com.amocrm.prototype D/OkHttp: --> POST https://andmhxsq.amocrm.com/private/api/v2/json/leads/set http/1.1
05-31 11:50:06.682 20489-20489/com.amocrm.prototype D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
05-31 11:50:06.682 20489-20489/com.amocrm.prototype D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 164
05-31 11:50:06.682 20489-20489/com.amocrm.prototype D/OkHttp: Cookie: BITRIX_SM_LOGIN=amodeveloper%40yandex.ru; expires=Wed, 05-May-2021 08:50:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.amocrm.com;BITRIX_SM_SALE_UID=0; expires=Fri, 26-May-2017 08:50:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.amocrm.com;session_id=h44nqh6np985fj5dhe9jqs1ensnh4ga0gdf6sbr10o76kv53nb81; path=/; domain=.amocrm.com;user_lang=en; expires=Mon, 31-May-2021 08:50:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.amocrm.com;
05-31 11:50:06.682 20489-20489/com.amocrm.prototype D/OkHttp: {"request":{"leads":{"update":[{"id":"40604699","last_modified":"1464684606","name":"Lead with many custom field","pipeline_id":"171910","status_id":"10753387"}]}}}
05-31 11:50:06.683 20489-20489/com.amocrm.prototype D/OkHttp: --> END POST (164-byte body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your server supports HTTP 2 protocol. If it doesn't, that might be a problem since Retrofit2 uses the latest available protocol by default. Retrofit service is usually initialised with OkHttpClient which default supported protocols are: HTTP 1.1, SPDY 3.1 and HTTP2. The most recent among them is HTTP 2.

If you want to set HTTP 1.1 to be supported you should set it explicitly:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setProtocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);
```

Remember to add only `Protocol.HTTP_1_1`.

Comment: Good attempt, but OPs first line in the log contradicts it: `--> POST https://andmhxsq.amocrm.com/private/api/v2/json/leads/set http/1.1`.  The client would not send that if it was using HTTP2

Comment: True. Did not notice that.